# Why won't my handleLogout funtion work in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement user auth, using react, react redux, and axios. My problem right now is when I click my logout button on my header, I want it to remove both access and refresh tokens from local storage, that get set at login. With the code I have now, I get no errors, but nothing happens when logout button gets clicked.

My handleLogout function:

```
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleLogout = () => {
        logout(history);
    };
```

my logout action that the above function uses:

```
export const logout = (history) => (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
    console.log('Made it here');
    dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
    });
    history.push('/');
};
```

It seems to never reach this action as my console.log('made it here') never gets outputted.

material ui button with onClick set to use function:

```
<Button
color="primary"
variant="outlined"
className={classes.link}
onClick={handleLogout}
>
    Logout
</Button>
```

Comment: I think you should call `logout` with `dispatch` in your `handleLogout`. E.g. `dispatch(logout(history))`

Comment: Are you using ES6 classes? If so, you'll need to bind your handler in your constructor function.

Comment: Did you have a look at your local storage? I have never worked with react but it seems like you're just returning a function onClick instead of executing one.

Comment: `logout(history)` returns a function, but what calls that function?  Are you trying to use Redex in some way but are outside the context of Redux actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `logout` function returns an arrow function, and that function expects an argument `dispatch`, you also need to pass-in that argument in order to work.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

// inside your component
const history = useHistory();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

function handleLogout() {
    logout(history)(dispatch);
};
```

Depending on your implementation, you might also import your dispatch dependency directly, and not pass-in it as an argument, so you can avoid returning a function which returns another function.